# regarding the usage of np.all along with axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I tried to test the usage of `np.all`, the test array `a` is

```
 a=array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]]])

b = [255,0,255]
c = np.all(a==b,axis=1)
```

I got

```
c= array([[False,  True, False],
   [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

I don't understand how was `TRUE` in c obtained from running `np.all(a==b,axis=1)`.

Comment: Because `0==0`.

Comment: What does the boolean array `a == b` look like? How many dimensions does it have? `np.all(..., axis =1)` - which dimension has to be *all True*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are calling [np.all()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) with `axis=1`, a logical AND will be performed over the first dimension i.e. all the columns (numbering starts from zero).

Your array is:

```
a = np.array([[[0,   0,   0],
            [0,   0,   0],
            [0,   0,   0],
            [0,   0,   0]],

           [[0,   0, 255],
            [255, 0, 255],
            [0,   0,   0],
            [255,   255,   0]]])
```

So, the first column of `a` i.e. `[0, 0, 0, 0]` and the first element of `b` i.e. `255` will go through an AND operation, giving the result `False`. All operations are given below:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0] & 255 => False
[0, 0, 0, 0] & 0 => True
[0, 0, 0, 0] & 255 => False

[0, 255, 0, 255] & 255 => False
[0, 255, 0, 0] & 0 => False
[255, 255, 0, 0] & 255 => False
```

This will give the end result of:

```
[[False  True False]
 [False False False]]
```

Since, you are not passing the `keepdims=True` parameter, the resulting list is of shape `[2, 3]` i.e. from `[2, 4, 3]` and `[1, 1, 3]` (see [NumPy broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules)), the operation is performed on `index=1`. Otherwise, the result would be of shape `[2, 1, 3]`.

Comment: Very thorough! Could you please explain to me the difference between: axis=0, axis=1, axis=2? I believe that 1 is for columns and 2 is for rows, but what's 0 for?

Comment: `axis` is synonymous with the array's shape index. In the array above of shape `(2, 4, 3)`, axis=0 corresponds to `2`, axis=1 to `4`, and so on. In the above example I'm doing an expansion with axis=1 (meaning vertically across rows), so I get the resulting shape `(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 2):

The key is understanding how `b` broadcasts with `a`.

`a` is (2,4,3) (I like the different dimensions).

`b` is (3,), which broadcasts to (1,1,3).

```
In [708]: a==b
Out[708]: 
array([[[False,  True, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False,  True, False]],

       [[False,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

The `all` is applied on axis=1, the size 4 one (columns in the display).  The result is then (2,3) shape.

The same broadcasting and axis reduction occurs in:

```
In [709]: (a+b).sum(axis=1)
Out[709]: 
array([[1020,    0, 1020],
       [1530,  255, 1530]])
```